# Bash Shell: How do I sort by values on last column, but ignoring the header of a file?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

**file**

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Average_Winter_Grade
323 Popa Arianna 10
317 Tabarcea Andreea 5.24
326 Balan Ionut 9.935
327 Balan Tudor-Emanuel 8.4
329 Lungu Iulian-Gabriel 7.78
365 Brailean Mircea 7.615
365 Popescu Anca-Maria 7.38
398 Acatrinei Andrei 8
```

How do I sort it by last column, except for the header ?

This is what **file** should look like after the changes:

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Average_Winter_Grade
323 Popa Arianna 10
326 Balan Ionut 9.935
327 Balan Tudor-Emanuel 8.4
398 Acatrinei Andrei 8
329 Lungu Iulian-Gabriel 7.78
365 Brailean Mircea 7.615    
365 Popescu Anca-Maria 7.38
317 Tabarcea Andreea 5.24
```

Comment: 1. Extract first line and print it. 2. Extract all lines except first. 3. Sort them. ...

Comment: @KamilCuk doing this `first_line=$(head -n 1 fil)` and `rest=$(more file | tail -n +2 | sort -g -r -k4,4)` gets rid of all endlines in **file**. Even cat does the same thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `more file |`

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=604945

Comment: `first_line=$(sed 1q file); rest=$( sed 1d file | sort ...)`

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2):

If it's always 4th column:

```
head -n 1 file; tail -n +2 file | sort -n -r -k 4,4
```

If all you know is that it's the last column:

```
head -n 1 file; tail -n +2 file | awk '{print $NF,$0}'  | sort -n -r | cut  -f2- -d' '
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd like to just sort by the last column, but `sort` doesn't allow you to do that easily.  So rewrite the data with the column to be sorted at the beginning of each line:

Ignoring the header for the moment (although this will often work by itself):

```
 awk '{print $NF, $0 | "sort -nr" }' input | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

If you do need to trim the order (eg, it's getting mixed in the sort), you can do things like:

```
< input awk 'NR==1; NR>1 {print $NF, $0 | "sh -c \"sort -nr | cut -d \\\  -f 2-\"" }'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1{ print " ", $0} NR>1 {print $NF, $0 | "sort -nr" }' OFS=\; input | cut -d \; -f 2-
```